# Google script to push 1d array into 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, push

I have an array of URLs pulled from the files in a folder, which I need to add to another array.

Array1 = [url1 , url2 , url3]

Array2 = [ [1 , 2] , [3 , 4] , [5 , 6] ]

I need the URL's to be distributed into each index, like:

Array2 = [ [url1 , 1 , 2] , [url2 , 3 , 4] , [url3 , 5 , 6] ]

Do I need to use a for loop, or concat, I'm unsure.

I've tried `Array2.push([Array1])`, but end up with all of Array1 in the first index position, rather than distributed through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`

```
Array2 = Array2.map( ( s, i ) => ( s.unshift( Array1[ i ] ), s ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var Array1 = ["url1" , "url2" , "url3"]

var Array2 = [ [1 , 2] , [3 , 4] , [5 , 6] ];

Array2 = Array2.map( ( s, i ) => ( s.unshift( Array1[ i ] ), s ) );

console.log( Array2 );
```

**Edit**

Equivalent function without arrows

```
Array2 = Array2.map( function( s, i ){
  s.unshift( Array1[ i ] );
  return s;
});
```

Comment: For some reason the google script editor gives me a syntax error if I try to use Array2 = Array2.map( ( s, i ) => ( s.unshift( Array1[ i ] ), s ) );

Comment: Is the arrow function not supported in your browser? If not, I can give a normal function.

Comment: I think its the arrow function, I'm using chrome, maybe google doesn't support it?